# Handle AJAX requests in separated directory/files

Tags: php, symfony

I want to move my all methods from controller, which are executed by AJAX request, to separate folder. For example create file `UserBundle/Ajax/Ajax.php` and put in this file, my all AJAX request methods.

Is it the right approach, to separate ajax requests, from normal http requests? I can't find any examples how to do it. It is possible in Symfony? I must extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` in this `Ajax.php` file? That will be okay, that will be exist two folders in bundle `Ajax` and `Controller`, contains controllers but first for ajax request and second for normal http request?

Do You know any architectural pattern, for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any problem to do that, only make sure to define the routing path correctly:

An example for annotation routing:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
app_bundle:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

app_bundle_ajax:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Ajax"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

> I must extend Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller in this Ajax.php file?

It's not mandatory, but the `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` provide you excellent shortcuts like [`$this->json(...);`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#json-helper) since Symfony 3.1

Comment: I would rather name it: `@AppBundle/AjaxController`

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple AjaxController as a service which will receive the ajax requests. Then you can redirect each of the requests to different Controllers and they will return JsonResponces().